# How to start remote Xorg/gnome via ssh & Xforwarding, then close ssh but without shutting down Xorg/gnome?

Tags: ssh, linux, x11forwarding, wine

Question:

I have a Linux server where I connect to via ssh.
It works fine, and also, X-forwarding works fine (in the local network).

Now I wanted to run a server program under wine. because it's a Windows application, it doesn't run on the command line, so I have to start it via x-forwarding. So far not a problem, works wonderfully.

My problem is I connect to the target computer with X-forwarding, like this: 
`ssh ip.of.target.computer -X`

then I start

```
gnome-session
```

from the ssh terminal. Gnome loads and i can start the graphical server application via wine. But when I want to logout from the X-forwarding, that closes the gnome-session (and the server X-window-application)...

How can I login, start a X-window application, and then logout ssh without closing the X-application ?

Answer (score 3):

You might find the `-N` option useful:

> ```
>  -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for‐
>          warding ports (protocol version 2 only).
> ```

and/or the `-T` option:

> ```
>  -T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
> ```

That way you won't get a shell prompt.

Try combining it with `disown`.

```
ssh <host> -X -N -T &
disown %<number>
```

where `<number>` is whatever number is printed in bracket after running the `ssh` command.

For example:

```
$ ssh -X -N -T myserver&
[1] 10317
$ disown %1
```

That will detach `ssh` from the shell and window, so you can close the window and `ssh` will keep running.

Comment: The bottom line is, -N is useless because the server initially is in console mode, not xorg mode.

Answer (score -1):

You could run X on the remote machine and use x11vnc to manage running apps remotely.